# RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver "package name" : NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I know that this question is a duplicated. But I couldn't find a proper solution for my case here. 
I'am developing a Android Clock Widget, and every thing running smoothly on my Nexus 4 and on my brother's hTC One X device. But on other devices, Galaxy SII, SIII, and Nexus 10 the app crashes once the configuration activity appears, and shows the Force Stop message because of NPE at this line:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Here is the method that contains that line:

```
    public void update(Context context, int nn){
         final RemoteViews localRemoteViews = create(context);
         prefsFile.getBoolean(String.valueOf(nn) + "app_onclick", true)) {
         packageName = prefsFile.getString("packageName", "Not Available");


         PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
         i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
         i = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         localRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img, pendingIntent);
         }
     widgetManager.updateAppWidget(nn, localRemoteViews);
   }
```

onReceive:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent n)
   {
super.onReceive(context, n);
prefsFile = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
         ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),    getClass().getName());
         widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
         WidgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(localComponentName);
   if ((paramIntent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) &&       (this.mAppWidgetIds.length > 0))
     {
         for (int n : this.WidgetIds) {
                packageName = prefsFile.getString("packageName", "Not Available");
                update(context, n);
            }
 }
 }
```

Manifest:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.koshmen.clock.aimen"
   android:versionCode="8"
   android:versionName="1.3.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >    
    <receiver
        android:name="com.koshmen.clock.aimen.Yarab"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.koshmen.clock.aimen.YarabConfig"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the Logcat result from the LogCat app installed on my phones that I couldn't use them on my PC, and the context was from the onReceive method that passes the context with the widgetID (n).
Why the app running on some devices and not on others? and giving the NPE error?

[update method](http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y403/aimen77/update_zps9bcc7519.png)
[onReceive method](http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y403/aimen77/onReceive_zps7cf3b080.png)

**And here is the latest log from the Eclipse logCat:**

```
05-24 01:47:56.863: D/dalvikvm(23665): JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (0 bytes 4/0)
05-24 01:47:56.863: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 481K, 41% free 9988K/16904K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
05-24 01:47:56.983: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 502K, 41% free 9998K/16936K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
05-24 01:47:57.068: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 41% free 10003K/16936K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
05-24 01:47:57.068: I/dalvikvm-heap(23665): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.453MB for 1468960-byte allocation
05-24 01:47:57.088: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 38% free 11438K/18372K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
05-24 01:47:57.153: D/mali_winsys(23665): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
05-24 01:47:57.183: D/OpenGLRenderer(23665): Enabling debug mode 0
05-24 01:47:59.323: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 38% free 11519K/18372K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
05-24 01:48:07.733: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 38% free 11531K/18392K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
05-24 01:48:07.733: I/dalvikvm-heap(23665): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.721MB for 186640-byte allocation
05-24 01:48:07.768: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 37% free 11713K/18576K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
05-24 01:48:07.808: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 37% free 11713K/18576K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
05-24 01:48:07.808: I/dalvikvm-heap(23665): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.899MB for 186640-byte allocation
05-24 01:48:07.848: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 37% free 11895K/18760K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
05-24 01:48:07.893: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 37% free 12078K/18944K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
05-24 01:48:07.958: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 36% free 12263K/19128K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
05-24 01:48:07.988: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 36% free 12445K/19312K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
05-24 01:48:08.018: D/dalvikvm(23665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 35% free 12810K/19680K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
05-24 01:48:08.028: D/AndroidRuntime(23665): Shutting down VM
05-24 01:48:08.028: W/dalvikvm(23665): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ebba8)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665): Process: com.koshmen.clock.aimen, PID: 23665
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.koshmen.clock.aimen.Yarab: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2426)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(Native Method)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:261)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:224)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at com.koshmen.clock.aimen.Yarab.update(Yarab.java:251)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at com.koshmen.clock.aimen.Yarab.onReceive(Yarab.java:226)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2419)
05-24 01:48:08.028: E/AndroidRuntime(23665):    ... 14 more
05-24 01:48:09.783: I/Process(23665): Sending signal. PID: 23665 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The two code listings do not match (first parameter name differs). Please provide *one* code listing that is *correct*, plus the full stack trace. Also, you have a bunch of useless lines in there, as you are wiping out your first `Intent` and replacing it with `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`. Finally, are you sure that there *is* a launch `Intent` for whatever package you are pulling out of your preferences?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also let us know what you pass as "context" in that method. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare Post edited, help

Comment: You are not crashing in an `updateWidget()` method. You are crashing in an `update()` method. Please post the code to the `update()` method, showing the line on which you are crashing. You might consider also posting the `onReceive()` implementation that calls `update()`.

Comment: BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } to com.koshmen.clock.aimen/.Yarab requires android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED due to sender null (uid 1000)

Comment: Edited. Sorry for being late @CommonsWare

Comment: Do you need/have that permission (RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) in your manifest file?

Comment: @fasteque the permission already added in the Manifest:

Comment: Please post your manifest because if it's declared it shouldn't give that log. Thanks!

Comment: @fasteque Manifest is here now

Comment: It is impossible for you to get a `NullPointerException` on the line you claim is the one that is getting the exception. A `NullPointerException` is when you invoke a method on `null`. The only thing that you are invoking a method on, in the line you claim has the crash, is the `PendingIntent` class, which cannot be `null`. I can only assume that you have the wrong line, and it is crashing somewhere else in `update()`.

Comment: Please the full manifest. I see just a portion of it. Also what you have declared is just an intent filter for your receiver to be notified when the boot is completed, but this is not the permission. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'am sure that the error was at the line where the PendinigIntet was.

Comment: @fasteque the full manifest is there now

Comment: In the <manifest> element add:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: The Error occurred when I send the apk from my Nexus 4 to the other devices, since as I mentioned above that I couldn't use them with my PC.
Also the hTC was giving me the same error, but when I install its drivers and run the project directly from Eclipse it gave me the error once and by the second try worked fine !!! strange ha?

Comment: @fasteque and what the intent action do in this case?
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: Leave it of course. You just have to add the permission. Look one of the many examples you can find around to see how to correctly set the permission: http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/tag/receive_boot_completed/

Comment: I tried last adding the BOOT permission last night and the same error still exist!

Comment: Check the link above. Try again and please post the updated manifest and the log you are getting now with the new manifest.

Comment: I'll post the results soon, just 15 minutes

Comment: @fasteque the log updated. And the same error appears at the PendingIntent line !!! HELP

Comment: Ok but did you check the Intent i is not null? You have a NPE.

Comment: it is not NULL, since it works on both Nexus 4 an hTC One X
Check out the 2 images for both methods, update &monReceive

Comment: Well, if that is the correct line where the NPE occurs, so context or i could be null. Check to be sure on a device where it crashes, don't exclude this possibility just because on another device it doesn't.

Comment: @fasteque thank you for your time, mate. I'll try and let you know

Comment: If you didn't change the code since you took the log, NPE occurs at line 251 of the method update. Please double check is still the one you have sent us. Thanks.

Comment: @fasteque yes, I post the log and the 2 images as they appear on there. I mean the NPE is as the line 251 now, at the
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: @fasteque The logcat updated from the Eclipse directly

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is coming from the method `PendingIntent.getActivity()` and it happens when trying to call a method on the `Intent` argument that you pass in this call:

```
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,
                           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The variable `i` is `null`.

In your code, you do this:

```
     i = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,
                           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Because it is possible for the call to `PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()` to return `null`, you'll need to add code that checks for that condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I used the same as you suggest, check the code above. @david wasser

Comment: No, you don't. You don't check for the possibility of `i == null` before calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't. At least it is working now. Thank you sir @David Wasser for you help, really appreciate

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue just by replacing the **true** to **false** in this line:

```
prefsFile.getBoolean(String.valueOf(nn) + "app_onclick", true)) {
```

and now it is working on all real devices and emulators.